# Using Toolbar and Cast SDK with minsdk="14" without v7-appcompat

Tags: android, android-support-library, google-cast

I have an app that supports Android v14 and up.  I'd like to use the Cast SDK, as well as some of the Material features that were added to v7-appcompat.  I'm currently using v13-support, which wraps v4-support but let's you use real Fragments.

Is there any way to use the Cast SDK back to v14 without incurring the cost of using *FragmentActivity* et al? Needing to replace all my styles/themes and base classes, go find every reference to *getFragmentManager* and replace them all with *getSupportFragmentManager* so on, and so on...?

The features that I"m interested in from v7 support library have seemingly nothing to do with Faux Fragments or Faux Holo themes...the idea of refactoring the whole app to use the Faux Fragments in order to use Cast seems audacious.

Anybody know an alternative?

(the app i'm working on has backwards compatibility issues beyond the v7 support library, so using v7 wouldn't change the fact that the app needs to be 14+)

Comment: I backported `MediaRouteActionProvider` and required classes to work with the native action bar: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-mediarouter. I have not tried it yet on Android 5.0, and I have only used with `RemotePlaybackClient` (versus the Cast SDK).

Comment: Note: you should still consider using AppCompat to support Material Design and API21 styles in a backward compatible way. It doesn't help your one time cost, but the cost of building a Material Design for API21 and switching to AppCompat (and getting that design 'for free' on older devices) is about the same so why not AppCompat? :)

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have a few months before I really need to start thinking about a public release with Material, and I"m blindly hoping that Google will add the missing pieces to v13 to save me the pain.  I'm starting to think the chances of that happening are slim...

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for fighting the good fight.